Using the same home route but for the different layouts in the React-Router-Dom
So, I have a task where I need to change the home route element depending on the current layout.
The problem is that I have no idea how to do this without making them interfere with each other. Is this thing would be even possible?
So, here is what the main idea was:
export const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='login' element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path='registration' element={<RegistrationPage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/' element={<PrivateLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<ExpensesPage />} />
          <Route path='statistics' element={<StatisticsPage />} />
          <Route path='budgets' element={<BudgetsPage />} />
          <Route path='settings' element={<SettingsPage />}>
            <Route path='change-avatar' element={<ChangeAvatarPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

And of course, it didn't work out. It would also be great if I couldn't access the RootLayout if it is already in the PrivateLayout, which is accessible after the auth. Please help or tell me if this is possible to achieve. I appreciate any help you can provide.
EDIT: so, to be clear I've already solved the problem by checking in different layouts if the user is logged in by searching for the accessToken, but I still wonder if something like changing the home route depending on the user already logged in by using only react-router-dom and not tweaking the layouts code.

Since you want to use multiple layouts and multiple layout route components on the same route path, I think the best you can do is to simply check the authentication status and conditionally render one or the other. If you are looking for clean routing code I'd suggest creating another layout route component that conditionally renders either the RootLayout or the PrivateLayout component, and then render a nested route that conditionally renders either the ExpensesPage or the HomePage component.
Example Code:
const RootOrPrivateLayout = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = /* however this is computed in your code */;

  return isAuthenticated ? <PrivateLayout /> : <RootLayout />;
};

const isAuthenticated = /* however this is computed in your code */;

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<RootOrPrivateLayout />}>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={isAuthenticated ? <ExpensesPage /> : <HomePage />}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="registration" element={<RegistrationPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<PrivateLayout />}>
        <Route path="statistics" element={<StatisticsPage />} />
        <Route path="budgets" element={<BudgetsPage />} />
        <Route path="settings" element={<SettingsPage />}>
          <Route path="change-avatar" element={<ChangeAvatarPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

If you liked, you could also abstract isAuthenticated ? <ExpensesPage /> : <HomePage /> into a React component to further clean up the routing code.
